# In Firemonkey TLabel changes height when Autosize checked

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, autosize, tlabel

Can anyone explain why `Firemonkey` `TLabel` changes from its default `Height` of 15 to a new `Height` of 18, when `AutoSize` is checked. The `Font` properties remain the same.

I have looked at `Unit FMX.Controls` and found the `Implementation` section.The `Constructor` shows default of 15.

> FMX.Controls Lines 2305..2392

I have also checked out `TStyledSettings`, but to no avail, so I was wondering if it has anything to do with Styles at all.

I did notice that in the `Delphi VCL`, `AutoSize` is Checked by default, whereas in `FireMonkey` it is not. (Probably not relevant).

Any thoughts as to why this could be. It is annoying having to change `Height` when I change to AutoSize.

Comment: Are you sure it's not just sizing itself to the height of the current font?

Comment: No, as I said in the question, all the font properties remain the same.